# Is there a saying in Portuguese equivalent to "to skate over thin ice"?

Tags: tradução-inglês, ditados

To "skate over thin ice" refers to a subject which is dangerous or unwise to talk about. Literally it means "patinar sobre gelo fino".  However neither a Brazilian nor a Portuguese would say that, especially because nobody goes ice-skating either in Brazil or Portugal. Is there a saying which conveys the same in Portuguese?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Parece-me algo como *brincar com fogo*, *cutucar a onça com vara curta*, *mexer num vespeiro* e possivelmente outros nessa linha. Coisas que devem ser evitadas, ou feitas com extrema cautela, *pisando em ovos*.

Comment: "calma, se você vai comentar isso com ela, você vai estar pisando em ovos".  É, gostei.  +1

Comment: ou "mexendo no vespeiro" também

Comment: "Mexendo no vespeiro" é ótima.

Answer (score 6):

Para além da tradução literal "patinar em gelo fino", que nao é inapropriada em certos contextos, há expressões idiomáticas que se podem usar, como os seguintes ditados portugueses:

- pisar em ramo verde;
- caminhar na corda bamba.

Referência: [Linguee](http://www.linguee.pt/ingles-portugues/traducao/skate+on+thin+ice.html).